# INSERT INTO ... SELECT, need insert no more than one element per query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have 2 tables

```
zr1f4_k2_tags
id          int(11) AUTONUMERIC
name        varchar(255)  UNIQUE
published   smallint(6)
```

and

```
zr1f4_k2_tags_xref
id          int(11) AUTONUMERIC
tagID       int(11)
itemID      int(11)
```

I want to populate zr1f4_k2_tags_xref

This query does what i need

```
insert into zr1f4_k2_tags_xref (id, tagID, itemID) select NULL, id, @itemID from zr1f4_k2_tags where zr1f4_k2_tags.name=@tagName
```

but it has one problem, after adding items to the zr1f4_k2_tags_xref it will duplicate entries like it would be finding the tagmane more than once on zr1f4_k2_tags which is false cause its declared as unique.

I need to add one reg to zr1f4_k2_tags_xref by each query, and it sometimes adds the same thing over and over with only one query.

the 1st element is added just fine. i dont get it.

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html it says that it generates a temporarly table but i dont get how does it works exactly.

Thanks for your time!!

EDIT:

Ill make another example to help clarify my problem, my sql skills are poor I've always relay on doing more queries being very inefficient but now I want to improve my sql skills and also i need the speed in this particular project

this pseudo code its how i would achieve it using 2 queries.

select id from zr1f4_k2_tags where name="foo" as Tag_ID

note the Tag_ID on the insert is coming from the 1st select query

INSERT INTO zr1f4_k2_tags_xref (tagID, itemID) VALUES (Tag_ID, @MyItemID);

Comment: Have you run the select portion of your query directly and see what it returns?

Comment: Are you sure your query is run only once?

Comment: I was almost sure but for debuging sake, I just double checked it and yes the query just runs once.

its pretty weird cause it its suppose to search the id with the tagname on the table "thezr1f4_k2_tags" to then add the reference on "zr1f4_k2_tags_xref". i can do it with 2 queries but I'm trying to improve speed ill hear any sugerencies and again thanks for your time.

Comment: thx for your comment  @Chris Dunaway it really helped me to get closer to the cause.

This is what it returns

Inserted rows: 6
Inserted row id: 6 (Query took 0.0081 sec)
SQL query:
INSERT INTO zr1f4_k2_tags_xref( tagID, itemID )
SELECT id, 1
FROM zr1f4_k2_tags
WHERE zr1f4_k2_tags.name = "phone" 

made the query manually just executed once and it "inserted 6 rows"

i must add that there is only one row containing "phone" in the "thezr1f4_k2_tags" table since its field name is declared as unique.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway u solved my problem i finally tracked my problem somehow the field name is not unique anymore :/

i wish i could give you reputation also i have no idea how to mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
insert into zr1f4_k2_tags_xref (tagID, itemID) select id, @itemID from zr1f4_k2_tags where zr1f4_k2_tags.name=@tagName
```

Comment: just tested and it generates the same result =/, thx for your time anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem - each time you run the query it inserts ALL the values, not just new ones.

```
insert into zr1f4_k2_tags_xref (tagID, itemID) 
select id, @itemID 
from zr1f4_k2_tags 
where zr1f4_k2_tags.name=@tagName
and zr1f4_k2_tags.id not in (select id from zr1f4_k2_tags_xref)
```

If not correct please explain why

Comment: thx for ur time @Sam Makin just solved the problem it was just me being dumb the field, i set as unique in the real database was not set unique in the test enviroment that was just all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

thx to @Chris Dunaway i solved this the problem was that somehow the field i set unique was not really unique on the test environment.